# "Missing \begin{document}" after DeclareUnicodeCharacter

Tags: unicode

When compiling this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{27e3}{somereplacement}
\begin{document}

Hi, world! P ⟣ Q

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

```
> pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 ...lareUnicodeCharacter{27e3}{somereplacement}
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution is that I should spell `27E3` in uppercase.

Comment: Why did you ask a question that's about a typo and that you already knew the answer to?

Comment: So that others in the future can search for the problem and find an answer. It's recommended by StackExchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer .

Comment: No, I agree with the principle, but I thought this was stretching it a bit when the error is caused by mistyping the hexadecimal number. I think it would be much better if you asked a question like "Why do hexadecimal numbers for unicode glyphs have to be typed with uppercase letters?" and then provide a MWE with `27e3` and `27E3` to show the difference. Then some TeX wizard can enlighten us about why this is so.

Comment: I agree with @Sverre; it is not necessary to "document" every possible mistake as it can be distracting.  For a tiny error like that, a useful answer would provide some explanation.

Comment: It's fine to post a self-answer after one has asked a question and one finds the error/solution oneself, after some hours, but this is rather a report ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I agree with you on that, but clearly it was not the case here.

Comment: It's taken me more than an hour to find the solution; I had already converted my 32 ``\DeclareUnicodeCharacters`` to ``\newunicodechar`` as a workaround. Does that count?

(I'm converting a document with Unicode text into LaTeX.)

Comment: I am "another user in the future" and I joined the site (which was overdue anyway) just to confirm that this has saved me time.  Thanks!

Comment: Years after the original posting, this saved me an unknown amount of time when I used the uppercase for a bold capital delta (Δ) with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D6AB}{∆}` which typeset perfectly. Some of my confusion comes from Shapecatcher.com's use of the lowercase when displaying the Unicode hexadecimal code as `0x1d6ab` (which would not typeset correctly for me). Thanks @BramGeron for posting the question and answer. This is all part of my conversion from the LaTeX to LuaLaTeX typesetting engine.